Removing images from Google Artifacts Registry
As a part of the deploy stage in Github Actions, I build and push my images to GCP's Artifacts Registry:
- name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
  id: auth
  uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
  with:
    credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}

- name: Configure Docker to use gcloud for auth
  run: gcloud --quiet auth configure-docker

  ...

- name: Setup Docker Buildx
  uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3

- name: Build and push image
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
  with:
    context: .
    build-args: |
      PYPI_USERNAME=${{ secrets.PYPI_USERNAME }}
      PYPI_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.PYPI_PASSWORD }}
    push: true
    tags: "${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE }}:${{ github.sha }}"
    cache-from: type=gha,scope=${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE }}
    cache-to: type=gha,mode=max,scope=${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE }}

The images are tagged with the commit's SHA.
Now, I want to periodically cross-reference images that are actually in use in my GKE cluster and those that are present in the registry — and clean up the unused ones. Retrieving lists of images is easy:

For the registry: gcloud artifacts docker images list us-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT_ID/gcr.io --include-tags
For the cluster: kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{..image}"

But what are those untagged images in my registry and why don't the tagged ones have size?

I guess those are the underlying layers or whatnot, the main question is: using which combination of flags and arguments should I delete an image (and all its auxiliary stuff) associated with a particular tag? See: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/artifacts/docker/images/delete.
I'm mostly concerned with not leaving any leftovers behind, while also not breaking anything not related to the tagged image I want to purge

UPDATE: Tried deleting by tag, leftovers are still there in the UI.
before:

after:


I empathize with your tidiness but are your registry artifact costs so significant that this is compelling? If you're too precise, could you not inadvertently delete an image (digest) that is still needed (or wanted to be not deleted?) "I had temporarily deleted the Deployment to do some analysis and, when I tried to redeploy, the image had been deleted?". GKE garbage collects unused images so that issue is addressed. Could you possibly implement a more general-purpose policy of having images older than x months being purged?

It would be useful to mark images as "archived" in a registry such that pulls failed but the archive could be quickly "unarchived" if needed.

Tags are optional so I assume those images in your registry that aren't tagged, weren't tagged. I suspect (!?) that the None size are failed pushes (this should be relatively easy to confirm by trying to run them). It's curious that you have 1484 sized images too... Are those expected?

@DazWilkin, the snippet from GitHub Actions is the only thing that's pushing images to this registry, so no untagged images are being pushed there, as well as there wasn't a single failure to push something to this registry. So I'm too confused with this list, that's why I posted this question in the first place.

I just don't like the idea that this registry will be forever growing or that some cleanup policy will delete images based on their date, while they may be just some stable images that have been running for a year straight.

This is the problem: how can you tell -- without mistake -- that nothing takes a dependency on an image|manifest. I think if you could define that, you could publish it and implement it as a policy. I'm unsure whether "it's not currently being used by a Kubernetes Pod" is strong enough of a case. But, I don't know your infrastructure.

Part of your policy could be (1) any images without a tag will be deleted (I don't know if this is true, just a conjecture); (2) any images of size 'none' will be deleted; (3) any images older than x months that aren't currently deployed against this public set of runtimes (GKE list of clusters; Cloud Run etc. etc.) will be deleted.

Google Artifact Registry supports several options to delete images:

From the console you can manually delete entries.
From the CLI, there is a gcloud artifacts docker images delete.
From the OCI API, you can delete manifests by tag.
From the OCI API, if the manifest is untagged, you can delete it by digest.

For the first two options, see the Google documentation: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/manage-images#deleting_images
For the OCI APIs, those are documented in the OCI spec, but it's probably easier to use a tool like crane (from Google), oras (from Microsoft), skopeo (from RedHat), or regclient (from myself). Specifically with regclient, the regctl command line lets you do this as a one-off or shell script, and the regbot command allows you to write your own retention policies as Lua scripts to periodically run against your repository.

Thanks, will try to cook something with your tool :)

Could you please help me understand why a single explicit push results into ~3 things being actually pushed into the registry and why gcloud artifacts docker images delete image:tag leaves several leftovers behind (see the update in the original post)?

Review the tagged manifest before you attempt to delete it. You'll likely find that it's a manifest list or OCI Index, used for packaging multi-platform images, and Docker also uses them for packaging build attestations. The docs indicate that unreferenced layers are deleted daily. I'm not sure if similar rules apply to untagged manifest. Other Google docs describe how you can create a cleanup policy: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/repositories/cleanup-policy
